# Play facebook video in UIWebView

Tags: ios, facebook, uiwebview

Does anyone know how to play a facebook video in a `UIWebView`?

My app uploads video to facebook and retrieves the video's url. I'd like to embed this url into a `UIWebView` to play back. I've worked this out for youtube but not Facebook. looking for help.

Comment: I assume you would need a few things:

1) the url
2) if it's a video that someone posted, you'll have to have them log in and give you proper permissions.

Comment: Could you provide the code you've tried thus far?

Answer (score 5):

Orpheus!

I’m a few years late lol, but I’ll post the answer here anyway -- in Swift since it’s 2018 ;) -- just in case someone needs it.

You can use the following HTML string:

```
let embedCode = "<iframe src=\"https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=\([INSERT VIDEO URL])&show_text=0&width=\(Int([INSERT WIDTH]))\" width=\"\(Int([INSERT WIDTH]))\" height=\"\(Int([INSERT WIDTH] * 56.25))\" style=\"border:none;overflow:hidden\" scrolling=\”no\" frameborder=\"0\" allowTransparency=\”true\" allowFullScreen=\"true\"></iframe>"
```

where you replace [INSERT VIDEO URL] with the video URL and [INSERT WIDTH] with the desired web view width.

Then load the HTML into the `UIWebView` like so:

```
webView.loadHTMLString(embedCode, baseURL: nil)
```