# Share video from users phone Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, video

The user makes a video with my app and saves the video to their phone in directory. I wondering would it be possible to share the video that is stored on the user's phone to facebook via open graph.  I have tried many things for a couple of days and even posted questions but i couldn't figure it out.  So all i am wondering is it possible to share a video stored on users phone to facebook via open graph, and after video is shared facebook via open graph i can delete video from users phone?  Any tips and directions would be appreciated. I am programming in objective c for ios.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

[How-To: Use the Graph API to Upload a Video (iOS)](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/08/04/how-to--use-the-graph-api-to-upload-a-video--ios/)

try this code from stack-overflow [ThIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6619769/iphone-sharekit-with-video-upload-for-facebook/11408084#11408084)

Also try :[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976569/how-to-upload-video-on-facebook-using-iphone-sdk-4-0)